# Validation Script not getting called while using AJax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using below code on my main page ,where other pages are loaded using ajax with the help of TWO RADIO BUTTONS

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  if(str=="Candidate")
  {
     xmlhttp.open("GET","creg.php",true);       
  }
  else if(str=="Employer")
  {     
     xmlhttp.open("GET","Empyr.php",true);
  }

xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

below script is written for FORM VALIDATION (written at end of main page),this script works only when main page loaded first time ,but when forms are getting loaded second time using ajax than this script is not working

```
<script>
$.validate({
  form : '#cand, #employerRegister'
})
; 
</script>
```

As i know script is getting read at the time of page load ,but now Where should I write this script so that it works when I load forms using ajax,where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using validation engine? I will not prefere doing ajax call with pure javascript it looks messy.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#registration').validate({

        rules:{

            email: {
                    email: true
                },
            password : {
                minlength : 6
            },
            repassword : {
                minlength : 6,
                equalTo : "#password"
            }

        },


        submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form

        var post = {};

        form_data = $(form).serialize();
        //console.log(form_data);
        //console.log(book_form);

        if(post)
        {
              $.post(site_url+'/members/register',form_data,
                   function(response){  
                        var res1 = $.parseJSON(response);
                        console.log(res1);
                        if(res1.success == true )
                        {
                                $('.success_message').html('You are successfully registered ').show();
                                window.location.href = site_url+'/pages/registerstep';

                                clear_form(form);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('.error_message').html(res1.success).show();
                            //clear_form(form);
                        }

                   }

            ); 
        }
    }
  });
```

});

Use something like this. This will work. Reason why your code is not working after first load is because your validation is not triggering while form submit

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code again to bind the event handler, after the new element is inserted into the DOM. It is better to use cross platform javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototypejs](http://prototypejs.org/) etc

You need to call the bellow javascript again from ajax response

```
<script>
$.validate({
  form : '#cand, #employerRegister'
})
; 
</script>
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961405/why-jquery-design-script-is-not-working-for-the-products-returned-by-ajax-script#comment35058140_22961405)

Comment: `function applyScript()
{alert("2");
 $.validate({
  form : '#cand, #employerRegister'
})
; 
}` did it like this , `alert 2` is getting fired but validate is not working,what mistake is there please do suggest

Comment: did like this ,not yet working ,`function applyScript()
{
alert("2");
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $.validate({
   form : '#cand, #employerRegister'
 });
 });
}`

Comment: check of form element exists after ajax call using formelement.length

Comment: Check document.getElementById("cand").length